# Parse.com Swift Multiple Class Query

Tags: swift, parse-platform, querying

I'm using Parse.com to store my user information but struggling to figure the following out.

With Parse.com I have three classes:

1) User

2) Place

3) SavedPlace

SavedPlace is a class which associates the User with a Place which the user saved. For each place in SavedPlace, there is the User and Place pointer as well as some additional notes created by the user.

In my app, I want to retrieve the list of the user's saved places into a TableView with the Place info (i.e. name, location, image) and the notes.

My current method is:

1) Query SavedPlace for all the saved places and return an array of Place objectIDs

2) Lookup each objectID in Place class and return the Place information.

Is there a more efficient way where I can query Parse once for all of the user's saved places and return all the relevant information from the Place class?

Thanks

Comment: If you would like to make it the process faster, you should save the SavedPlaces in the PFUser. Then you could use PFUser.currentUser()?["SavedPlaces"] Hope this helps.

Comment: Are they really pointers in SavedPlace?  The question uses the word "pointer", but your step 1) refers to "an array of objectIDs".  Array of pointers == good... array of objectIDs == bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is.

`PFQuery` has a method called `includeKey:`, which allows you to add objects that will be returned with your query, in your case, you want to get the users and places related to the SavedPlace instances, right? So you do this:

```
let query = SavedPlace.query()
query.includeKey("place")
query.includeKey("user")
query.findObjects...
```

The result will be a list of `SavedPlace` objects with a pointer for `user` and `place`, where those objects have already been fetched, so all their fields (that aren't pointers) will be available to you.

You can even use dot notation with that method, so if you have a pointer in your `Place` class called `Country` and you want to fetch it as well, you can add `query.includeKey("place.country")` and it will be included in the query.

The best thing about this is that it will count as a single call.

Here's more information about `includeKey`

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/queries-for-relational-data/